# Why are some parameters of builtin functions prefixed with '__'?

Tags: python

I noticed that some builtins have paramenters prefixed with '__'.

For example `repr` with `def repr(__obj) -> str` as signature.

Is this only a naming convention for builtins or does it also have a functional purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has no effect on the runtime and is an old naming convention. Before Python had [positional-only arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/), developers would mark arguments with double underscores to indicate that they should *only* be called by position, not by name. So, in the case of `repr`, the double underscore indicates that you should always write `repr(whatever)`, never `repr(__obj=whatever)`.

Nowadays, in modern Python, we would be more likely to write

```
def repr(obj, /): ...
```

But going back through and changing all standard library functions to do so isn't a priority and would likely be considered a breaking change.

Comment: I suspect it's mostly just the not-a-priority reason. A lot of these cases couldn't be breaking changes since the C parts of Python have had access to positional-only arguments since forever, and it was very common for builtins to have positional-only parameters since the beginning of Python. (Technically written-in-Python functions could roll their own positional-only arguments on top of `*args`, but there wasn't any as-nice-as-normal-arguments ways to do it, whereas in C any argument handling was about equally annoying but positional-only was maybe arguably a little simpler/shorter/easier.)